# Change stage background color in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, background-color

I am using pure AS3 to build my project. I was wondering if there are anyways to change the stage background color through AS3...Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

like this:

```
[SWF(backgroundColor="0xec9900")]
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    }
```

Comment: The question is 'Change **stage** background...' and this answer tells you how to change the color of main MXML. Main MXML is a child of stage. Correct answer is `stage.color = 0xABCDEF` that gave Peter Gibson.

Comment: @PatrickS His answer works with pure AS3. He just polluted his answer with crap you don't need.

Answer (score 10):

I have this in a `creationComplete` handler

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="on_init();">

private function on_init():void {
    stage.color = 0x000000;
}
```

Though I have a feeling it would work anywhere.

Comment: There is no 'color' property for stage? Flash Player 10?

Comment: Could be - this was flex4.6 on Flash Player 11 from memory

Comment: This answer is almost a perfect answer to the question above. When stage isn't null you can peek and poke the color of it. There is also an event: `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddToStage);` (just remove the xml crap, I use pure AS3 and it works)

Answer (score 9):

This creates a shape and add it to the stage behind everything. To change the color anytime call: `changeBGColor(0xFF0000)` (to red)

It also maintains the size of the background (covering all area) when the windows is resized.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

var default_bg_color:uint = 0xffffff;

var bgshape:Sprite;
stage.align = "TL";
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";

function initBG()
{
    bgshape = new Sprite();
    bgshape.graphics.beginFill(default_bg_color);
    bgshape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
    addChildAt(bgshape, 0);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeBGWithStage);
}
function changeBGColor(color:uint) 
{
    bgshape.graphics.beginFill(color);
    bgshape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}
function resizeBGWithStage(e:Event)
{
    try {
        bgshape.width = stage.stageWidth;
        bgshape.height = stage.stageHeight;
    } catch(e){}
}

initBG();
```

Comment: Thanks Makram...but Wopdoowop's way is much easier... :D +1 though

Comment: Interresting as an abstract class for every stages !

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the following line of Actionscript 3.0 to set the background color. 0x000000 for black, 0xFFFFFF for white and anything in between.

this.stage.color = 0x00000;

Answer (score 4):

You can set background colour on initialization, the way @Wopdoowop mentioned, but if you want to change it dynamically you would need to create your own bitmap/sprite/movieclip that would act as a background (should go below the rest of your content and have width and height of your stage) and change colour of that bitmap/sprite/movieclip.

Answer (score 1):

```
[SWF(width='700',height='525',backgroundColor='#000000',frameRate='30')]
public class RunTime extends Sprite {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the backgroundColor of the application object.

Comment: Thanks...would you please explain more details? I have tried google but couldn't find anything.....Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a sprite and then making it in the back. This is the way I would do it.

Make sure to `import flash.display.Sprite;`

```
var bkg:Sprite=new Sprite();
//replace the 0x000000 with a hex code.
bkg.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1)
bkg.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight)
bkg.graphics.endFill()
addChild(bkg)
```

a plus about this is that you can draw a background (if you want) either manually or with the code and then put it in through the code.