# Flash Builder: Change stage background color with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I'm not talking about a meta/binding, such as:

```
[SWF(backgroundColor="0xec9900")]
```

I need to be able to change the color on the fly.

Comment: hope this will work for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432408/change-stage-background-color-in-as3

Answer (score 1):

Draw a rectangle into a Sprite and add it to the stage as the lowest level child.

```
var bg:Sprite;

function changeStageColor( color : uint ) : void {
    bg ||= new Sprite();
    bg.graphics.clear();
    bg.graphics.beginFill( color, 1 );
    bg.graphics.drawRect( 0,0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );
    bg.graphics.endFill();
    stage.addChildAt( bg, 0 );
}
```

Usage:

```
changeStageColor( 0xFF0000 );
```

Comment: bg ||= new Sprite(); ?  what does ||= do?

Comment: That's lazy instantiation.  Shorthand for: `if (bg == null) bg = new Sprite();`

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "doesn't seem to work"? Errors? Not the desired effect? I've tested the code - it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my main sprite :

```
this.opaqueBackground = 0xff0000;
```

Answer (score 0):

In initialize I put:

```
this.backgroundSkin = new Quad(this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight, 0x007800);
```